# Subtract UIView from another UIView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, mask

I'm sure this is a very simple thing to do, but I can't seem to wrap my head around the logic.

I have two UIViews. One black, semi-transparent and "full-screen" ("overlayView"), another one on top, smaller and resizeable ("cropView"). It's pretty much a crop-view setup, where I want to "dim" out the areas of an underlying image that are not being cropped.

My question is: How do I go about this? I'm sure my approach should be with CALayers and masks, but no matter what I try, I can't get behind the logic.

This is what I have right now:

[image: This is what it looks like]

This is what I would want it to look like:

[image: This is what I want it to look like]

How do I achieve this result in Swift?

Comment: Show the code for what you have currently

Comment: Not much code to show. It's pretty much only two simple views above each other with different frame sizes.

Comment: So have you tried using masks, or drawing paths in the overlay?

Comment: Yes, that's what I did, but none of the code worked, so I got rid of it. Like I said, I just can't seem to grasp the logic behind the layers and masks -> i.e. hierarchy of the views, what is masked, etc.

Comment: The idea is you show the code and we look at fixing it ;-) you want something like a full size layer with a background colour (this is the overlay view layer) and a masking layer in the middle which is transparent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be another drawing solution but basically you have 4 areas that need to be handled. Take the square area above and below the space with full width and add the right and left side between them with constraints to eachother.

Comment: I have thought about doing this, but this seems dirty. I was hoping there would be a more elegant solution using masks.

Comment: well, it seems less elegant, but the other solution is to make an image with the centerpart, then make the tint effect and add back the image on top of it. This solution has the drawback that you need to implement all the drawing yourself while for example the scrollview is handling this perfectly for zoom, slide, etc. Any drawing with CALayer would need the same logic.

Comment: Alright, this works just fine and seems to have no drawbacks. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Although you won't find a method such as `subtract(...)`, you can easily build a screen with an overlay and a transparent cut with the following code:

`Swift 4.2`

```
private func addOverlayView() {
    let overlayView = UIView(frame: self.bounds)
    let targetMaskLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    let squareSide = frame.width / 1.6
    let squareSize = CGSize(width: squareSide, height: squareSide)
    let squareOrigin = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(center.x) - (squareSide / 2),
                               y: CGFloat(center.y) - (squareSide / 2))
    let square = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(origin: squareOrigin, size: squareSize), cornerRadius: 16)

    let path = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds)
    path.append(square)

    targetMaskLayer.path = path.cgPath
    // Exclude intersected paths
    targetMaskLayer.fillRule = CAShapeLayerFillRule.evenOdd

    overlayView.layer.mask = targetMaskLayer
    overlayView.clipsToBounds = true
    overlayView.alpha = 0.6
    overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    addSubview(overlayView)
}
```

Just call this method inside your custom view's constructor or inside your ViewController's `viewDidLoad()`.

**Walkthrough**

First I create a raw overlayView, then a CAShapeLayer which I called "targetMaskLayer". The ultimate goal is to draw a square with the help of UIBezierPath inside that overlayView. After defining the square's dimensions, I set its `cgPath` as the targetMaskLayer's path.

Now comes an important part:

`targetMaskLayer.fillRule = CAShapeLayerFillRule.evenOdd`

**Here I basically configure the fill rule to exclude the intersection.**

Finally, I provide some styling to the overlayView and add it as a subview.

ps.: don't forget to `import UIKit`